# How many ways to select 5 clothes for 5 days with restrictions on what cloths can be used on certain days and clothes cannot be reused?

Tags: combinatorics

Martha has 5 clothes of different types, say, $\{C₁,C₂,...,C₅\}$ and she wants to wear all these clothes on different days, say, $\{D₁,D₂,...,D₅\}$. Due to some reason, $C₁$ must be used either at $D₃$ or at $D₄$ and $C₂$ can be used either at $D₄$ or at $D₃$ or at $D₅$. Every cloth is to be used for only one day, in how many ways can clothes be used?

I solved this problem as:

$\{C₁, C₂\}$ are reserved for specific days and hence remaining choices are only 3 and hence the number of possible ways the clothes can be used with the given restriction is $3+1+1 = 5$ ways.

Is this solution and answer correct?

Comment: Even assuming $C_1$ is used on $D_3$ and $C_2$ is used on $D_4$ you have three remaining clothes to permute among the remaining days for at least $3! = 6$ arrangements, already more than your "attempt" answer of $5$ and that is only the first possibility for how $C_1$ and $C_2$ are used, there are others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose when $C_1$ is used.  There are two options.

Regardless of the choice made for when $C_1$ was used, there will be two remaining options available for when $C_2$ is to be used.

Regardless what choice was made for $C_2$, there will be three remaining options for when $C_3$ will be used, and then two remaining options after that for when $C_4$ will be used and $C_5$ will necessarily be used in the final remaining day.

Apply rule of product and conclude.

> $2\times 2\times 3\times 2\times 1 = 24$

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach:

For each satisfying assignment of $C_1, C_2$, there will be $(3!)$ ways of assigning $C_3, C_4,$ and $C_5$.

From the constraints, either $C_2$ is assigned to $D_5$ or it isn't.

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~C_2 \to D_5}$
Then, $C_1$ has two choices: either $D_3$ or $D_4$. 
Total for Case 1: $(2)$ choices.

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~C_2 \not\to D_5}$
Then, $C_1$ and $C_2$ must both be assigned to $D_3,D_4$, in some order.
There are only two ways of doing this. 
Total for Case 2: $(2)$ choices.

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$ 
$[2 + 2] \times (3!).$